# CheckBox issues with images

Tags: ios, objective-c, checkbox

When I select the check box the second time it shows me the checked image, but the status is unchecked.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [CheckBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (IBAction)CheckBox:(id)sender {

    if (CheckBox.selected == NO)
    {
          CheckBox.selected = YES;
          [CheckBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];       
    }
    else
    {
          CheckBox.selected = NO;
          [CheckBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];     
    }
}
```

Comment: use sender to change property ... and why you have make variable names in upper case ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is totally right just you replace `UIControlStateSelected` to `UIControlStateNormal`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (sender.tag==0)
{
    sender.tag = 1;
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    
}
else
{
    sender.tag=0;
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need add normal image and selected images in IB itself (or in viewDidLoad) and toggle state for button in button action like below

```
- (IBAction)checkBoxAction:(UIButton *)sender {
  sender.selected = !sender.selected;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When create button for check box you can save address this element on array after click on every button first access to all object on array seved and set image unckeck and this button clicked set image checked.
Or
When create button for check box set tag different for every button and when click on button you should be set image unckeck for every button use tag number and set image check for button clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Also one thing,
Here you use CheckBox.selected = YES/NO;

So also you can write your code like:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        CheckBox.selected = NO;

        [CheckBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [CheckBox setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }

- (IBAction)CheckBox:(id)sender {

    if (CheckBox.selected == NO)
    {
          CheckBox.selected = YES;    
    }
    else
    {
          CheckBox.selected = NO;     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)changeState:(id)sender {

    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;

    if (btn.selected == NO)
    {
        btn.selected = YES;
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        btn.selected = NO;
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set boolean value to false in `viewDidLoad` and then in button click

```
- (IBAction)btnCheckBoxClick:(id)sender
{
    if (isChecked)
    {
        [btnCheckBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btncheckbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        isChecked = false;
    }
    else
    {
        [btnCheckBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btncheckbox_selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        isChecked = true;
    }
}
```